# Inserting each .post data into a <td> using .each

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, each, .post

I was wondering if this is possible to be done with jQuery. Please see following code.

**HTML**

```
<table id="order">
    <tr>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
        <td class="order_items"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.load_ads").each(function(){
        $(this).html("Place a New Ad Free!");
    });
    var count=$("td.load_ads").length;  //18
    $.post('/fetch_orders.php',{count:count},function(data){
        var data_arr=data.split('/end');
        for(index=0;index < data_arr.length;index++){  //for each of the array values got back from fetch orders.php
            .
            ..
            ... Stuck here. How to make each data_arr(ie: each data_arr[index]) go into each td?
```

.POST script

```
$count =$_POST['count'];
$query="SELECT * FROM orders1_manager_orders ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $count";
$db->setQuery($query);
$ads=$db->loadRowList();

foreach($ads as $ads_to_display){
    echo $orders_to_display[9].'/';
    echo $orders_to_display[10].'/end';
}
```

As explained in the title, I need each order to go into each empty `td` slot in the above html table. But, if I were to put a `.each()` function after my **.post**, all of my tds will turn into the first data gotten from the script, meaning `data_arr[1]`.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at JSON and how to use JSON with PHP for easy parsing.

Comment: i dont know exact answer, but using jquery, you can optimize the html code for table as 
$("#order td").addClass("order_items")
So that you dont need to add each td to the class individually.

Answer (score 1):

First, please have a look at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/

Second: better use div insted tables, this would make you independent of client device screen size.

http://csswizardry.com/2011/08/building-better-grid-systems/

Third, this is absolutly horrible code but it should be your solution:

```
$("td.load_ads").each(function(){
    $(this).html("Place a New Ad Free!");
});
var count=$("td.load_ads").length;  //18
$.post('/fetch_orders.php',{count:count},function(data){
    var data_arr = [];

    var rows=data.split('/end');
    for(index=0;index < rows.length;index++){  
        var row = rows[i].split('/');

        for (var x in row) {
            data_arr.push(row[x]);
        }
    }

    var i = 0;
    $("td.load_ads").each(function () {
        if (data_arr[i]) {
            $(this).html(data_arr[i]);
        }

        i++;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $query = Sql_Query("SELECT * FROM  Table");
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);              
    for($i=0; $i < $num_rows; $i=$i+5)
     {

        $query1 = Sql_Query("SELECT * FROM  Table LIMIT ".$i.", 5 ");
                print '<td valign="top">';
               while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query1))
                  {
                  print '<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group1[]" id="chk_group1" value="'.$row['isp_name'].'" />    '.$row['isp_name'].'<br />';

                     } 
                       print '</td>';

     }
```